# Automatically truncate and null terminate a string buffer in a buffer overflow

Tags: c++, winapi, truncate, buffer-overflow

I have following code, which can load text from all child windows of a specified parent window. It works fine, but sometimes, there are some parent windows (such as opened Notepad with a very long C++ source file) those have large amount of text and cause a buffer overflow.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(__in HWND hWnd, __in LPARAM lParam) {

    LRESULT TEXT_LENGTH = NULL;
    WCHAR szText[32767];
    LPWSTR szWindowText;
    UINT nBuffer = NULL, nText = NULL;

    szWindowText = reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(lParam); szText[0] = L'\0';
    nBuffer = (UINT)wcslen(szWindowText);
    TEXT_LENGTH = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, NULL, NULL);

    if (TEXT_LENGTH > NULL)
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)32767, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&szText));
        szText[TEXT_LENGTH] = L'\n'; szText[TEXT_LENGTH + 1] = L'\0';

        while ((nBuffer < 32766) && (szText[nText] != L'\0'))
        { szWindowText[nBuffer++] = szText[nText++]; }

        szWindowText[nBuffer] = L'\0';
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The line `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)32767, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&szText));` sometimes causes a buffer overflow and my application crashes.

I know how to detect this overflow like `if (TEXT_LENGTH > 32767)`, but I cannot dynamically increase the size of the buffer `szText`.

As the question title mentions, I don't want to increase its size, I just want to truncate and null terminate return text to maximum buffer size of `32767` (if `TEXT_LENGTH` is over `32767`) and assign it to `szWindowText` to be used for other purposes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't compare an integer to `NULL`, or initialize integers to it. `NULL` is supposed to be a null pointer. Even if defined as `0` using `NULL` is semantically wrong and misleading to people reading your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll keep this in mind. Thanks :-)

Comment: `WCHAR szText[32767]`!!! why don't use a std::wstring and resize it dynamically when you know the length?

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Thanks much! I will try it out!

Comment: And if you don't want to dynamically set length of a string, then why don't you cap the length to `min(32767, TEXT_LENGTH) - 1`?

Comment: `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)32767, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&szText));` should never cause buffer overflow as correct size of the buffer is supplied. Actually this temp buffer is not required at all. Your real problem is that you are writing into pointer supplied as  `lParam` without knowing destination buffer size.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Unless latest C++ string is used (that supports non-const `data()` method) string can not be used as buffer.

Comment: @VTT Yes it can, you can use `&some_string_object[0]` to get a pointer to the first element in the string (once resized properly).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what is the max buffer size for `WM_GETTEXT` message?

Comment: @Blueeyes789 I don't know. How about [reading the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: WM_GETTEXTLENGTH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. It's better to dynamically allocate the buffer to TEXT_LENGTH. (+1 for '\0')
2. Drop the & operator of szText in WM_GETTEXT, you just need the address contained, not the address of the pointer
3. When you explicitly use char's, use SendMessageA, otherwise visual studio defaults to wchar_t with SendMessageW. SendMessage is a macro which expands to wchar_t or char depending on your project settings. Or use TCHAR type with SendMessage which expands to the correct type also.

---

```
DWORD l = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, NULL, NULL);

if (l > 0){
   TCHAR *szText = new TCHAR[l + 1];
   SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)l + 1, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(szText));

  // use szText

   delete[] szText;
}
```

Comment: This answer does affect buffer overrun problem mentioned by OP. Also it suggest to do the wrong thing: to use chars or TCHAR instead of explicitly using wide chars and W versions of functions. And the posted code snippet contains errors: `WPARAM` to `SendMessage` should contain destination buffer **capacity**, that is should be `l + 1` and the value returned by second `SendMessage` call should be inspected as well to determine the number of characters actually copied into buffer (thought it is unlikely that it won't be the same as `l`).

Comment: Ok, fixed the buffer capacity problem. However, I dont agree with the "use wide char and W versions" opinion. In my opinion, you should always use TCHAR, LPTSTR etc and the macro versions of win32 API functions (so non 'W' or 'A') so the program adapts to whatever is configured in the project settings

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to make room for the `\n`, whyever you're inserting that, and the way to do that is to use `sizeof szText-1` instead of 32767 in the `WM_GETTEXT` call.

NB If you must use Simonyi notation, don't use it where it doesn't apply. There is nothing null-terminated about `szText`, which you are only using for the result of `WM_GETTEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

`SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)32767, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&szText));` should never cause buffer overflow as correct size of the buffer is supplied. Actually this temp buffer is not required at all.

Your real problem is that you are appending characters into pointer supplied as `lParam` without knowing destination buffer size. You should at supply destination buffer size.